# Pouring Water, where goes wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have finished [Pouring Water](https://www.spoj.pl/problems/POUR1/) from SPOJ. However, the system keeps giving *wrong answer*. But I cannot find out where goes wrong.

Please give a hint. Test cases are also appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

int countFromA (int a, int b, int c);

int main() {
    int t;
    std::cin>>t;
    std::cin.ignore(5, '\n'); // SPOJ error: iostream limit
    while (t--) {
        int a, b, c;
        std::cin>>a>>b>>c;
        if (c == 0) {
            std::cout<<"0"<<std::endl;
        }
        else if (a == c || b == c) {
            std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
        }
        else if ((a < c && b < c) || (a == b)) {
            std::cout<<"-1"<<std::endl;
        }
        else {
            int fromA = countFromA (a, b, c);
            int fromB = countFromA (b, a, c);
            int result;
            if (fromA == -1) {
                result = fromB;
            }
            else if (fromB == -1) {
                result = fromA;
            }
            else if (fromA <= fromB) {
                result = fromA;
            }
            else {
                result = fromB;
            }
            std::cout<<result<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int countFromA (int a, int b, int c) {
    int times = 0;
    int a_in = 0;
    int b_in = 0;
    // fill a
    a_in = a;
    times++;
    while (true) {
        // a->b & test
        if (a_in > (b - b_in)) {
            a_in = a_in - (b - b_in);
            b_in = b;
            times++;
            if (a_in == c) {
                return times;
            }
        }
        else {
            b_in = b_in + a_in;
            a_in = 0;
            times++;
```

**Answer:** should add a test here. I was coding in the assumption of `a > b`, and when reusing it, I forgot.

```
        }
        // fill a / empty b
        if (b_in == b) {
            b_in = 0;
        }
        else {
            a_in = a;
        }
        times++;
        // finish
        if (a_in == b - b_in) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

My algorithm first check special cases `if` `else if` `else if`, and then do the main calculation in `else`. For the `else` part, I've written a function to pour from first variable to second variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint.  Since this is a coding exercise for your benefit I won't give you the full answer.

You have 4 different operations that you might need to combine in any sequence to get your answer.  Suppose that your numbers are `21, 3, 15`.  You need to look at both repeatedly dumping `b` into `a` until you have `15` in there, or fill `a`, keep pouring it into `b` then dumping `b` until you have `15` left.  Your current operation just tries a single sequence of operations.  You need to somehow try *both* from scratch then pick the best one.

Comment: I've tried both `int fromA = countFromA (a, b, c); int fromB = countFromA (b, a, c);`. You see the first is `a, b` and the second is `b, a`.

Comment: @Dante Jiang: It looks to me like `countFromA` won't notice if `b_in` winds up with the answer you are looking for after dumping all of `a` in.

Comment: could you please kindly provide me a failing case?

Comment: @Dante Jiang: Try `5, 33, 20`.